# c# mysql unable to output query to a textbox

Tags: c#, mysql

here is my code:

```
private void searchInDatabase()
{
    MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost; username=root; password=123456; port=3306");
    MySqlCommand mcd;
    MySqlDataReader mdr;
    String query;

    try 
    {
        c.Open();
        query = "SELECT * FROM test.classmates WHERE first_name ='"+searchName.Text+"'";
        mcd = new MySqlCommand(query, c);
        mdr = mcd.ExecuteReader();
        if(mdr.Read())
        {
            firstName.Text = mdr.GetString("first_name");
            middleName.Text = mdr.GetString("middle_name");
            lastName.Text = mdr.GetString("last_name");
            age.Text = mdr.GetString("age");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Result Not Found");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: "+error.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        c.Close();
    }
}
```

I would like to ask for a help if I have missed on anything or I am doing it wrong. If you have free time, I will much appreciate it if you will comment the perfect way to do I implement this problem: I want to get data from MySQL then put it in a textbox.

Comment: What error / problem you have now? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: As a side note you should use a parameter for searchName in your query, here's a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements, also could you include where firstName, middleName, lastName, and age are defined?

Comment: My problem is I can't get data from my database then output the data to my c# program, specifically into a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN you need to pass the column number as parameter

```
public override string GetString(int i)
```

So try to pass the column number (starts from 0) of your column name. Assuming the first_name is the first column of your table then

```
firstName.Text = mdr.GetString(0);
```

**UPDATE**

Try to use MySqlConnectionStringBuilder

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
conn_string.Server = "serverip/localhost";
conn_string.UserID = "my_user";
conn_string.Password = "password";
conn_string.Database = "my_db";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString();
```

Comment: actually my query for adding data to the database is working, but when i retrieve data from my database then output it in a textbox, that's my problem. I can't output data from my database to my program's textbox.

Comment: have you tried to use the column number as i stated earlier.

Comment: can you post here your exception

Comment: nope not yet, I will try it later. Thank you for replying!

Answer (score 0):

First of all look at this sample of connection string and change your connection string:
`'Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPasswor;'`
If connection is OK send erorr message or full exception.

Comment: It doesn't look like it solves the OPs problem. Have you tested it?